# Check Constraint - Subqueries are not allowed in this context

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, constraints

I tried to add a **Check Constraint** and I have only failed so far. What would be the way to get around this:

> Msg 1046, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>
> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions
>   are allowed.

This is the code:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.PropertySeasonDiscount ADD CONSTRAINT
[CC_PropertySeasonDiscount_MadeFrom_MadeTo]
CHECK (
    (SELECT COUNT(PropertySeasonDiscountId) FROM dbo.PropertySeasonDiscounts apsdeb 
        WHERE 
            (apsdeb.PropertySeasonId = PropertySeasonId) AND
            (
                (apsdeb.ValidForReservationsMadeTo >= ValidForReservationsMadeFrom AND ValidForReservationsMadeFrom >= apsdeb.ValidForReservationsMadeFrom) OR
                (apsdeb.ValidForReservationsMadeFrom <= ValidForReservationsMadeTo AND ValidForReservationsMadeTo <= apsdeb.ValidForReservationsMadeTo)
            )
    ) = 0
);
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand I put the logic inside a UDF and return the value for that UDF. Then I compared against it inside the constraint and it didn't complain. Would trigger be better?

Comment: @AaronBertrand It didn't complain when I created but it acts unexpectedly when I try to add value into table.

Comment: A trigger can be a bit easier to manage. In addition an `INSTEAD OF` trigger can prevent other constraints from being validated when the row is inserted (since you can just bail out of the insert altogether if your check doesn't validate).

Comment: You have to be careful, whatever route you go down, that you cover interesting edge cases. E.g. what happens if a single insert statement contains two rows that have an undesirable overlap - you need to be considering the *current* rows in the table, and *all of* the new rows to be added as a whole.

Comment: Are `dbo.PropertySeasonDiscount` and `dbo.PropertySeasonDiscounts` the same table? (Is it plural or not, or are they actually two different tables?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SQL Server does not currently support subqueries for CHECK CONSTRAINTs.

As you have discovered, there can be [trouble with CHECK constraints](https://web.archive.org/web/20100507204302/consultingblogs.emc.com/davidportas/archive/2007/02/19/Trouble-with-CHECK-Constraints.aspx) involving UDFs when attempting to circumvent the subquery limitation.

The alternative constraint implementation strategies are *triggered procedural* and *embedded procedural*. The former is preferred because, in common with declarative constraints, they cannot be circumvented.

Implementing a triggered procedural strategy that is well optimized and handles concurrency issues is non-trivial but still doable. I highly recommend the book [Applied Mathematics for Database Professionals  By Lex de Haan, Toon Koppelaars](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-uYZcnEt4uQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=applied+mathematics+for+database+professionals&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rYJgT7S3BcG_0QX7ouidBw&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=trigger&f=false), chapter 11 (the code examples are Oracle but can be easily ported to SQL Server).

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned already, this type of Check constraints is not yet implemented in SQL-Server. Besides triggers, you could also examine the possibility of changing the table's design.

A possible alternative includes storing the previous interval end-date in every row. See [Storing intervals of time with no overlaps](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/03/08/storing-intervals-of-time-with-no-overlaps.aspx) for details. The enforcing constraints are simple but there are complications on the way you'll have to deal with Inserts/Deletes/Updates on the table.

Another possibility would be to store not one row (with the start and end-date) for a discount as you do now but a whole series of rows (one for every date of the discount interval). The enforcing constraints will be even simpler but you'll have a lot of rows instead of every one of your current table.