# How to set hierarchic foreign key through another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am not sure if my title really explains the question, so I'll try an example:

Let's say I have:

1) *region* table: parent regions and subregions in the same table (link **A**)

2) *product* table: each product is linked to a single parent region (link **B**)

3) *product_price* table: lists the price of a product (**C**) in all sub regions of that product region (link **D** >>> the link in question).

(the diagram is showing only the relevant fields, there are a lot more data in *region* and *product*)
[image: tables diagram]

Is there a way to define the **region->region_price** key, to include only sub_region_id's of the parent_region in the **product->region** key??

Or, in the terms of the image, how do I make the **D** link to include only regions that are children [as in **A**] of the **B** & **C** link?

Hope you are getting my point...

Here are the real tables and links:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[product](
    [product_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [product_name] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [parent_region_id] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [product_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[product_price](
    [product_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [sub_region_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [price] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_product_price] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [product_id] ASC,
    [sub_region_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[region](
    [region_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [region_name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [parent_region_id] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_region] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [region_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[product]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_product_region] FOREIGN KEY([parent_region_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[region] ([region_id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[product] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_product_region]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[product_price]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_product_price_product] FOREIGN KEY([product_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[product] ([product_id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[product_price] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_product_price_product]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[product_price]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_product_price_region] FOREIGN KEY([sub_region_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[region] ([region_id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[product_price] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_product_price_region]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[region]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [HK_region_region] FOREIGN KEY([parent_region_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[region] ([region_id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[region] CHECK CONSTRAINT [HK_region_region]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000698/sub-queries-in-check-constraint

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to enforce a business rule with a database rule, but they're not always the same. Instead, you can run validation querys in your code before inserting or updating, or you could implement a trigger that validates your rules or throws an error.

Comment: you are right, it is a businees rule, but I wanted it to be a database rule so entity framework gets it