# "Not include" Constraint?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Thanks for reading this.

I have tables like this in `MySQL`:

[image]

`Device` table has a list of name. And `ReservedName` table has a list of "reserved" name list.

As you may see, my design concept is to make `Name` value of `Device` table SHOULD NOT one of `Name` in `ReservedName`.

I could easily implement this relation by add a few SQL statement when I do INSERT operation to `Device` table. But I am wondering if there is something like "Not one of" constraint in the table schema? Maybe opposite meaning of FOREIGN KEY? It is also welcome if there is any other way to make that relationship.

Comment: you're looking for a check constraint.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000698/sub-queries-in-check-constraint may be useful

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `BEFORE INSERT` triggers which can either cause an error or set the field to its default value when the requirements of the data are not met.

In your case you can create a trigger, which will raise error, if your validation fails, something like following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `validate_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `Device`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT* FROM ReservedName WHERE Name = new.Name) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT := 'check constraint on Device.Name failed';
    END IF;
END
```

You can read more about MySQL triggeres in [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html).