# Sql Query error in check statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, relation

I've to Define a table constraint on Dept that will ensure that all managers have age > 30.
I'm a beginner in it so I do not want to use user defined function.
Here I want a simple solution. which can apply my check in create table statement.
I want to use check statement or assertion statement.

```
create table emp(eid int primary key,ename varchar(20),age int,salary real CHECK (salary >= 10000));
create table dept(did int primary key, buget real,managerid int foreign key (managerid) references emp check ((select eid from emp where age >30)));
```

and its giving the following error i do not know why

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 54
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 54
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

> I'm using Microsoft sql management studio 2014.

Tell me where I'm doing wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't store the `age` as a fixed value, since you'll need to update it every time the age changes. Store the date of birth instead and have the `age` be a computed column

Comment: Give a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880698/can-a-check-constraint-relate-to-another-table  or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000698/sub-queries-in-check-constraint

Comment: What you're describing is a business rule. Not a data integrity rule. As such, it's better to implement that rule in the application layer rather than the database layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without a UDF.  You can use a foreign key constraint and computed columns.

```
create table emp (
    eid int primary key,
    ename varchar(20),
    age int,
    salary real CHECK (salary >= 10000),
    manager_eligible as (case when age > 30 then 1 else 0 end),
    unique (manager_eligible, eid)
);

create table dept(
    did int primary key,
    buget real,
    managerid int,
    manager_eligible as (1),
    foreign key (manager_eligible, managerid) references emp(manager_eligible, eid)
);
```

I should add that UDFs usually slow things down.  So being able to do this with foreign keys should also make inserts and updates faster.

Comment: can you provide a solution with check?

Comment: That is an interesting way of using a computed column with a foreign key. Pretty slick.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a User Defined Function.  Give a look at Give a look: [Can a Check constraint relate to another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880698/can-a-check-constraint-relate-to-another-table)  or  [Sub queries in check constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000698/sub-queries-in-check-constraint)