# How to CONSTRAINT such a condition? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I need to create a table `TEAMS` and create a constraint that the coach (`TeamCoachName`) can just be a coach for just 1 team (`TeamName`).

```
/* Table number 2: Teams */
CREATE TABLE TEAMS
(
    TeamName VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
    YearOfFounding INT,
    TeamOwnerName VARCHAR(255),
    StadiumName VARCHAR(255),
    GeographicArea VARCHAR(255) 
         CHECK (GeographicArea  IN ('North','Central','South')),
    TeamCoachName VARCHAR(255),

    CONSTRAINT Names UNIQUE (TeamName, TeamCoachName),
    CONSTRAINT OneTeamCoach
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sub queries in check constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000698/sub-queries-in-check-constraint)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your `Team` table, and if a coach can only be associated with 1 team row, then it is just a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on `TeamCoachName`.

Comment: I think you understood my question very well, that is my first time in SQL and I still don't know how to write it In the right way, can you please help me write the full line of code so I can execute it in server management ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a UDF that takes a `TeamName` and a `CoachName` and returns "true" if the `CoachName` is associated with any other team.

Then check the value of that function in the CHECK constraint.

(Although actually Jamie raises a good point.  If `TeamName` is also UNIQUE, then all you need is a UNIQUE constraint on `CoachName`.   The only way you would need my approach is if the same `TeamName` could appear in multiple rows.)