# Postgres: unique constraint on integer range

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given two integers, start and end, and a foreign key, how do I define a `unique` constraint on the interval start:end inclusive, and the foreign_key

Given I have the following entries in my table:

```
+-------+-----+--------------------------------------+
| start | end | foreign_key                          |
+-------+-----+--------------------------------------+
| 10    | 20  | 04ef8258-917c-46d6-8db3-9c704d3f4fbd |
+-------+-----+--------------------------------------+
| 40    | 60  | 04ef8258-917c-46d6-8db3-9c704d3f4fbd |
+-------+-----+--------------------------------------+
```

Then, the following inserts should fail:

```
+-------+-----+--------------------------------------+
| start | end | foreign_key                          |
+-------+-----+--------------------------------------+
| 30    | 50  | 04ef8258-917c-46d6-8db3-9c704d3f4fbd |
+-------+-----+--------------------------------------+
| 12    | 18  | 04ef8258-917c-46d6-8db3-9c704d3f4fbd |
+-------+-----+--------------------------------------+
```

What I have tried thus far:

```sql
alter table some_table
  add constraint unique_interval_to_foreign_key_constraint
    unique (start, end, foreign_key)
```

This does not work as it only defines the unique constraint on discrete points and the foreign key, and not the range.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you might be able to use a `CHECK` constraint with a subquery checking that no records exist overlapping the range, i.e., https://stackoverflow.com/a/13000715/8887313. Not sure that this is the most efficient way or even whether it will work...

Comment: Please see this solution:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/110583/211987

Comment: You want an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Additional question: How would I query such a table with the exclusion constraint i.e. how do I handle the ON CONFLICT UPDATE RETURNINg id case?

Answer (score 4):

Adding answer for completeness:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;

ALTER TABLE some_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT unique_interval_to_foreign_key_constraint
        EXCLUDE USING gist
        (foreign_key WITH =,
         int4range(start, end, '[]') WITH &&
        );
```