# Postgres UPSERT with EXCLUSION CONSTRAINT

Tags: sql, postgresql

### Given the following table:

```sql
create table some_table
(
    id                 uuid      default uuid_generate_v4() not null,
    last_modified_date timestamp default now()              not null,
    foreign_key        text,
    start              integer,
    end                integer,
    constraint some_table_pkey
        primary key (id),
    constraint some_table_foreign_key_fkey
        foreign key (foreign_key) references foreign_table
);
```

Then I added the following constraints:

```sql
CREATE INDEX some_table_foreign_key_idx
    ON some_table (foreign_key);

ALTER table some_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT some_table_start_check
        check (start > 0);

ALTER TABLE some_table
    add CONSTRAINT some_table_check
        check (end >= start);

ALTER TABLE some_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT unique_interval_to_foreign_key_constraint
        EXCLUDE USING gist
        (foreign_key WITH =,
         int4range(start, end, '[]') WITH &&
        );
```

Generating a table like so:

```
+--------------------------------------+-------+-----+--------------------+--------------------------------------+
| id                                   | start | end | last_modified_date | foreign_key                          |
+--------------------------------------+-------+-----+--------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 04ef8258-917c-46d6-8db4-9c704d3f4fbd | 10    | 20  | timestampA         | 04ef8258-917c-46d6-8db3-9c704d3f4fbd |
+--------------------------------------+-------+-----+--------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 04ef8258-917c-46d6-8db5-9c704d3f4fbd | 40    | 60  | timestampB         | 04ef8258-917c-46d6-8db3-9c704d3f4fbd |
+--------------------------------------+-------+-----+--------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

### How do I `INSERT` a record into this table?

**What have I tried?**

```sql
INSERT INTO some_table (foreign_key, start, end) 
VALUES (`04ef8258-917c-46d6-8db3-9c704d3f4fbd`,  70, 80) 
ON CONFLICT (foreign_key, start, end) 
   DO UPDATE SET last_modified_date=NOW() RETURNING id;
```

I get the following error:

> UnableToExecuteStatementException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE requires inference specification or constraint name

Comment: `ON CONFLICT` does not support exclusion constraints.

Comment: What are my alternatives or work arounds?

Comment: Create an UNIQUE INDEX using (foreign_key, start, end) and use it.

Comment: @NatanMedeiros: I need the exclusion constraint because that satisfies my need. I posted a question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62880202/postgres-unique-constraint-on-integer-range)

Comment: With an exclusion constraint the new row can conflict with more than one existing row.  That is why an `on conflict update` could never work.

Comment: ahhha. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks @MikeOrganek