# A check constraints that checks whether two associated elements have same foreign key

Tags: sql, check-constraints

In the following scenario, I want to make sure that if you take a single entry of d, you can assume that it's associated b, and c have the same a_id:

```sql
CREATE TABLE A (
  id INT NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE B (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  a_id INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_b_a FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES A (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
);

CREATE TABLE C (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  a_id INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_c_a FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES A (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
);

CREATE TABLE D (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  b_id INT NOT NULL,
  c_id INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_d_b FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES B (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_d_c FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES C (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
);
```

Is there a way to ensure this with a check constraint? Or maybe my database design is flawed?

Comment: If this is with MSSQL It is doable with a function, check this post.
   If making a before insert trigger is an option, it should be easier.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63401557/sql-constraint-to-check-the-value-of-another-tables-column

Comment: If you're able to change the model, including `a_id` in `D` and making that part of the foreign key columns/referenced columns enforces the required constraint.