# How to add a constraint which refers to a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database, database-schema, check-constraints

Let's assume I have the tables **Job** *(JobPK INT etc.)* and **Employee** *(EmployeePK INT, Age INT etc.)*.

I want to create another table **A**, defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
   JobFK INT,
   EmployeeFK INT,
   CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (JobFK) REFERENCES Job(JobPK),
   CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeFK) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeePK)
)
```

where I can add only those employees whose age is greater than 25, for example.

How can I do that?

Comment: Note: Storing age is almost always a bad plan. Because you are *guaranteed* that on some unknown date in the next 366 days, it will become inaccurate. Storing Date of Birth and *deriving* age is usually far more sensible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding constraints that check a separate (linked) table for a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65825778/adding-constraints-that-check-a-separate-linked-table-for-a-value)

Answer (score 0):

I always implement these kind of limitations in the UI level (some validation plugins).

In SQL Server [CHECK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms179491(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) can be used

```
ALTER TABLE Employee  ADD CONSTRAINT CK_AGE
    CHECK (Age < 80 AND Age > 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a relation constraint or value constraint. It is impossible to have both on one constraint.

For a value constraint, you can define it in creating the table or add it later with `ADD CONSTRAINT`.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int CHECK (Age>=25)
);
```

You can't have a relation constraint that ensures just employees with an age greater than 25. relation constraint always applies on all records not a subset of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table tablename 
add fieldname datatype check(conditional expression);
```

Example :

```
alter table A
add age smalint check(age >= 25);
```

Comment: Please do not spam (link removed).

Answer (score 0):

Preferably do it at application level. Nevertheless you can implement it as a DB constraint

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
   EmployeePK INT identity(1,1) ,
   Age int,
   CONSTRAINT pk0 PRIMARY KEY (EmployeePK),
   CONSTRAINT uk1 UNIQUE (EmployeePK, Age)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
   JobFK INT,
   EmployeeFK INT,
   EmployeeAge INT CHECK (EmployeeAge >=25),
   CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeFK) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeePK),
   CONSTRAINT fk2 FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeFK, EmployeeAge) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeePK, Age) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Insert test data

```
insert Employee
values (30),(20);
insert A
values (100,1,30);
```

This queries will fail:

```
insert A
values (100,2,20);

update Employee 
set age = age-10
where age > 25;
```