# Validate number of rows depending on master row field value

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, t-sql, check-constraints

I need to add a constraint to validate that number of rows referencing master table is lower than value in master row, e.g we have a table 
`master(master_id int pk, max_val int)` and `slave(slave_id int pk, master_id fk ref master(master_id))` (so slave is de facto a colection of something), and I want that `count(master_id)` in `slave` is <= than `max_val` for this `master_id`.  I have a constraint

```
 constraint NO_MORE_PASS check ((select count(head_id) from parts p where 
 p.head_id = head_id) <= (select max_val from head where id = head_id));
```

(not sure if it is correct, however SQL Server tells that subqueries are not allowed (sql server 2017) so...).

I have also read [Check Constraint - Subqueries are not allowed in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722433/check-constraint-subqueries-are-not-allowed-in-this-context), so the question: is there any other alternative (I would like to avoid using trigger)?.

I'am using this in spring app with spring data jpa (and hibernate) - may be useful, but would like to make it on db side rather than in the app.
Nethertheless entity it is like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "route_parts")
data class RoutePart(
  @Id
  @Column(name = "route_part_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  var id: Long? = null,
//...

  @Column(nullable = false)
  var slots: Int? = null,

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name = "route_part_passengers",
    joinColumns = [(JoinColumn(name = "route_part_id"))],
    inverseJoinColumns = [(JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))]
  )
  var passengers: Set<ApplicationUser> = setOf()
)
```

and in that case `ApplicationUser` is a slave (or better - another table will be created, and actually this will be that slave table) limited by `slots` value.

### So the question is...

How can I achieve limiting number of `ApplicationUser` attached to each `RoutePart`

Comment: Use a check constraint that is based on a user defined function. I hope I will have some time tomorow to write a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your check constraints to be based on queries, you must use a user defined function for the check constraint to work with.
Here is a quick example:

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Parent
(
    Id int,
    MaxNumberOfChildren int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Child
(
    Id int,
    ParentId int
);
```

User defined function (All it does is return the difference between the `MaxNumberOfChildren` and the number of records in the `Child` table with the same `ParentId`):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RestrictNumbrOfChildren
(
    @ParentId int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN 
        (
            SELECT MaxNumberOfChildren
            FROM dbo.Parent
            WHERE Id = @ParentId
        )
        - 
        (
            SELECT COUNT(Id) 
            FROM dbo.Child
            WHERE ParentId = @ParentId
        )
END;
```

Add the check constraint to the `Child` table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Child
    ADD CONSTRAINT chk_childCount CHECK (dbo.RestrictNumbrOfChildren(ParentId) >= 0);
```

**And that's basically all you need**, unless `MaxNumberOfChildren` is nullable.
In that case, you should add `ISNULL()` to the first query, with either `0` if null means no children are allowed, or the maximum value of int (`2,147,483,647`) if null means no restriction on the number of children - so it becomes `SELECT ISNULL(MaxNumberOfChildren, 0)...` or `SELECT ISNULL(MaxNumberOfChildren, 2147483647)...`.

**To test the script**, let's insert some data to the `Parent` table:

```
INSERT INTO Parent (Id, MaxNumberOfChildren) VALUES
(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1);
```

And insert some valid data to the `Child` table:

```
INSERT INTO Child (Id, ParentId) VALUES
(1, 1), (2, 2);
```

So far, we have not exceeded the maximum number of records allowed. Now let's try to do that by insert some more data to the `Child` table:

```
INSERT INTO Child (Id, ParentId) VALUES
(3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1);
```

Now, this insert statement will fail with the error message:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chk_childCount". The conflict occurred in database "<your database name here>", table "dbo.Child", column 'ParentId'.

**[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/QLV59423)**

Comment: Nice idea - i will try it asap and give you a proper feedback. Nevertheless looks good, thank you :). However, you could leave 'sql server' in the title ;)

Comment: From the help section - [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): "You should not *force* a tag into your title.   ...**Avoid** inserting tags into titles in any of the following formats:

[tag]: [question title]..."